# Haskell accessing fields in custom data types

Tags: haskell, tree, custom-data-type

For an assignment I have to implement different functions for the custom data type tree (as defined below)

I would like to accees the 'Label' (node-value) of the root node of my tree using the faulty function `getNodeValue`. I'd be very grateful for some help on how to do this!

```
data Tree = Node (Label -> Label) Label [Tree]
type Label = Int

testTree = Node (+1) 0 [Node (+1) 1 [], Node (+1) 2 [], Node (+1) 3 []]

getNodeValue :: Tree -> Label
getNodeValue t = {... how does I custom types? ...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use a pattern match here to 'look' inside the Tree datatype. To get the value of the root node of the supplied tree you would have to do something like this:

```
getNodeValue :: Tree -> Label
getNodeValue (Node _ l _) = l
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for! I figured it would be something like this, but I couldn't figure out that I had to pass a constructor call aswell. For correctness' sake (Tree _ l _) actually should be (Node _ l _).

Comment: Yep, changed it just before. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

If changing the type definition is allowed, it is also possible to use the record syntax to have accessors automatically generated:

```
data Tree = Node
    { getUpdater :: (Label -> Label)
    , getNodeValue :: Label
    , getSubnodes :: [Tree]
    }
```